# Inserting multiple values in a table?

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

The following code is working fine to insert new values in one row of tables. But when I try to insert multiple values then in the output those values get saved twice in the table.

Please help me for the code that will work to insert multiple values in my tables.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 String strConnection = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MK;Integrated Security=true";

 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
 try
 {

 con.Open();

 SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

 sqlCmd.Connection = con;
 sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select table_name from information_schema.tables";

 SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

 DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
 sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
 comboBox1.DataSource = dtRecord;
 comboBox1.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
 comboBox1.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME";

 con.Close();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
 }
 private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
 var collection = this.dataGridView1.Rows;
 string output = "";
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in collection)
 {
 foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
 {
 if (cell.Value != null)
 {
 output += cell.Value.ToString() + " ";
 this.Text = output;
 }
 }
 }
 }
 private void PopulateGridView(string tablename)

 {

 if (tablename == "System.Data.DataRowView")
 return;
 String strConnection = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MK;Integrated Security=true";

 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
 try
 {

 con.Open();

 SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

 sqlCmd.Connection = con;
 sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select * from " + tablename;

 SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

 DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
 sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecord;

 con.Close();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
 }

 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 if (comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
 {
 PopulateGridView(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
 }
 }
 private void InsertInfo()
 {
 string connectionString = null;
 SqlConnection connection;
 SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

 connectionString = @"Data Source=HP\SQLEXPRESS;database=MK;Integrated Security=true";
 connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        foreach (int rowIndex in lstNewRows)
        {


            string insrtQry = "insert into " + comboBox1.Text + " values(";

            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells)
            {
                insrtQry += "'" + cell.Value.ToString() + "',";
            }

            insrtQry = insrtQry.TrimEnd(",".ToCharArray());

            insrtQry += ")";


 try
 {
 connection.Open();
 adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(insrtQry, connection);
 adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();



 MessageBox.Show("Row inserted !! ");
 connection.Close();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
 }
 }
 }





 private void insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 InsertInfo();
 }

 private void dataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
 lstNewRows.Add(e.Row.Index);
 }


 }
 }
```

Comment: btw, where is lstNewRows coming from? Is it a ListBox? or what?

Comment: i have declared this  List<int> lstNewRows = new List<int>();
in starting of the code...and im using a combo box

Comment: Did you try putting break point at the beginning of "InsertInfo()"? If this is being called twice somehow?

Comment: nopes,i did not please tell where to put the break point so that i can check

Comment: Already told. At the beginning (first line) of the InsertInfo() method.

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to create an `InsertCommand` for this purpose, you can just enter the SQL query into `CommandText` without setting the `InsertCommand`.

Comment: yup i have...but im not understanding it..please help

Comment: Breakpoints in C# http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s5p4.html

Answer (score 1):

try changing:

```
string insrtQry = "insert into " + comboBox1.Text + " values(";
```

To:

```
string insrtQry = "INSERT INTO table_name (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (@value1, @Value2, @value3)"
```

Also checkout SQL insert statements at MSDN.Microsoft.com by following the link [HERE.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/91bd10ce-c83b-4766-920b-2137ddc29908)

Good luck with your code!

UPDATE:

Okay i'm beginning to understand what your doing. You could try making the comboBox into a variable so something like:

```
if (comboBox1.Text  == "table1")
{
string insrtQry = "INSERT INTO table_name (field1, field2, field3) VALUES 
(@value1, @Value2, @value3)" 
} 
else
{ 

 string insrtQry = "INSERT INTO table_name2 (field1-2, field2-3, field3-4) VALUES 
 (values1, values2, values3)" 
}
```

Comment: no sir,i can't replace this line because i want to select any table from my combobox and then insert it with values

Comment: but sir i have got 2 different tables in my combobox...that means they have different fields so please help how to replace this code line

Comment: yes sir thanks a lot its working...but it is showing error in void of statements private void insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) and private void dataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)

Comment: Have you assigned your datdGridView any default variables, and or connected it with a database yet?

Comment: That is a fairly standard error, I would suggest starting by changing the void, "insertifo" to public rather than private to start with and see if that changes the eror

Comment: sir,this code is only helping to insert one value or two values in either of the tables ...it is not inserting more than 2 new row values

Comment: the number of opening and closing brackets are equal i.e. 22

Comment: expected class,delegate,enum interface or struct

Comment: This is inside a class correct? the code should look like: 


namespace MyNamespace  
{  
    public class MyClass  
    {  
        private void ClearEnteredValues(....etc....) { } // Your code here  
    }  
} 

Do you have this in your code?

Comment: well i hv corrected that error...but it has one error in  try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(insrtQry, connection);
                    adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
where insrtQry is stated as does not exist in current context..please help here

Comment: im using this try catch just after the if else loop suggested by you

Comment: Could you send/show me your code, by either editing your post or through email.

Comment: Try changing:  string connectionString = null; to: connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);   I doubt this will work but its a place to start :/

Comment: no sir that's not working...by this editing it is giving errors in other keywords

Comment: well it is showing errors in other keywords like connection,connection string etc stating they do not exist in current context....

Comment: sir the if else code u have suggested is not helping in adding values in more than one row...only the value i enter in first new row is saved

Answer (score 0):

I would preferred Table value type and pass it to stored procedure [or inline query although i do not preferred it]
Check this link for detail

http://www.christian-etter.de/?tag=sqldbtype-structured